# CD проекта, как реализовать?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция

*Всем привет, никогда не настраивал выкладку своего проекта автоматически, поэтому прошу помочь с организацией всего этого.*

Имеется проект, в стиле микро сервисной архитектуры с использованием docker-compose, все хранится на GitLab, репозитории имеют следующий вид:

- ServiceA - сервис A, хранит в себе исходный код + `Dockerfile`
- ServiceB - сервис B, хранит в себе исходный код + `Dockerfile`
- ServiceC - сервис C, хранит в себе исходный код + `Dockerfile`
- Application - Перечисляет в себе сервисы (ServiceA...C), посредством `git submodules` + `docker-compose.yml`;

*В `docker-compose` декларированы все сервисы из репозиториев (Помимо своих "модулей", перечислен docker-сервис из готового образа) и поэтому для запуска приложения достаточно, просто выполнить `docker-compose up -d --build`*

Существуют 2 среды:

- Staging - среда-приемки, тестовая, нет доступа по ssh
- Production - прод, есть доступ по ssh (лучше конечно не трогать ssh)

Хочется сделать следующие:

1. Когда я обновляю `master` - ветку, репозитория `Application`, обновление автоматически доставляется на Staging-среду и приложение обновляется.
2. Когда все было успешно протестировано на Staging-среде, можно было нажать на `кнопочку` (Подтвердить выкладку) и изменения доставлялись на Production-среду (Процесс аналогичному на Staging-среде).

Теперь собственно сам вопрос :)

Каким образом можно организовать данный процесс?
*Возможно по неопытности, я пропустил какие-то процессы, но которые должны быть.*

Comment: Слышал про приватные Docker репозитории, это может помочь в реализации данного процесса?

Comment: Нужно копать в сторону https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/, там есть про интеграцию с докером

Comment: @DmitryD как я понял мне нужно создать образ, а можно ли собрать его из docker-compose?

Comment: Вполне, кладете в каждый сервис `Dockerfile` и указываете в `docker-compose.yml` путь к каталогу с проектами. [Как тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52389869/11752991)

Comment: @DmitryD такая структура у меня уже есть, только вот вопрос можно ли все docker-сервисы из `docker-compose.yml`, запихнуть в 1 образ для того чтобы его отправить его в  хранилище?
В примере, который вы указали, демонстрирован только "up"

Comment: `docker-compose build` ?

Comment: @DmitryD, как я понял он билдит каждый сервис по отдельности в `docker images` - "много" сервисов

Comment: Хм, мб, не помню. Надо подумать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Имеется проект, в стиле микро сервисной архитектуры с использованием docker-compose, все хранится на GitLab, репозитории имеют следующий вид:
>
> Service A - сервис A, хранит в себе исходный код + `Dockerfile`

Во-первых, **желательно**, чтобы микросервиcы можно было деплоить отдельно.
В текущем описании конфигурация только в `Application stack`, а это не гибко.
Если `Service A` меняется, нужно менять `Application`.

**Решение**:

- своё [описание инфраструктуры](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/tree/06dd5917c1900d7f565a2dfc4a95cef0c58e39e4) `docker-compose.*.yml` (в том числе и `docker-compose.development.yml`, пользуемся `docker-compose.override.yml`, делая ссылку)
- описание `environment` docker-compose file (прямо в репозитории сервиса)
- свои тесты, **build & push** в docker registry или через `Application` (`.gitlab-ci.yml`)
- уменьшаем связность сервисов
- коммуникация через [external network](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/06dd5917c1900d7f565a2dfc4a95cef0c58e39e4/docker-compose.swarm.yml#L26)

> нет доступа по ssh
> есть доступ по ssh (лучше конечно не трогать ssh)

SSH вполне себе вариант для деплоя. Главное **не руками** через ssh.

> Application stack

Описываем в `.gitlab-ci.yml` qa, integration tests, деплои как `staging` / `production`. Тут же можно положить скрипты для автоматизации деплоя.

Разберем на [примере](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode).
Некий аналог `Application` моей реализации CD. Смотри `services/example` (аналог `Service A`)

Для автоматизации используется `bash` + `ansible`.

**Ansible**:

- Конфигурации серверов по `environment` и секреты (минимально шифруем `host_vars.yml`)
- [деплой через ssh](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/ansible/roles/deploy/tasks/main.yml) (передаем файл stack, после удаляем)

**Bash**:

- Проверки services, environments
- Merge docker-compose.*.yml в один стек (build / deploy)

Как выглядит:

`./build example staging`

Билдим сервис `example` и заливаем в registry. Помним, что в этот [момент нужны sources](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/build#L29).

Аналогично деплой.

```
./deploy example staging
```

Под капотом у нас ansible и ему скармливаем пароль от `vault` для secrets.
Можно использовать как [`group_vars`](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/ansible/environments/staging/group_vars/staging.yml), так и [`host_vars`](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/ansible/environments/staging/host_vars/example.yml).

`docker-compose.yml` приводим к одному виду с `ansible vars` и уже через ansible контролируем переменные (кроме development).

**Пример c gitlab**

```
image: afsmnghr/ansible-gitlab-runner:1.2.1

variables:
  ...

stages:
  - integration
  - production

.ssh: &ssh |
  eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  ssh-keyscan "$PROD_IP" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

.ansible: &ansible |
  # WARNING: Ansible refuses to read from a world-writeable folder
  chmod -v 600 "$(pwd)"
  echo "$ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD" > .vault

build:
  stage: integration
  before_script:
    - *ssh
    - *ansible
  script:
    - ./build example production
  after_script:
    - rm -f .vault
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    refs:
      - schedules
      - branches
      - develop

deploy:
  stage: production
  before_script:
    - *ssh
    - *ansible
  script:
    - ./deploy example production
  after_script:
    - rm -f .vault
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    refs:
      - schedules
      - branches
      - develop
```

Пушим тег в master (настраиваем политики). Начинает билд и деплой на прод.
Все легко реализовать, если базовые вещи можно описать простыми командами.

**Вместо заключения**

Основные проблемы и что может помочь:

- Автоматизация (ansible playbooks / roles)
- Secret management (ansible vault, hashicorp vault)
- Infra / servers inventory (ansible)
- IaC на каждый environment (много docker-compose файлов)

Comment: В первую очередь, хочу сказать вам Спасибо!, за уделенное время на ответ. Пока в вашем ответе для меня есть слепые зоны, но благо это гуглится :)
Как я понял `Ansible` - поможет мне в создании `.evv` (конфиг-данных) и синхронизации?
Насчет гибкости, каким образом можно обезопасить себе от ситуации, когда сервисы должны быть обновлены в последовательно или одновременно, к примеру: Есть `ServiceA` - в нем используется API от сервиса `ServiceB`, соответственно ситуация когда  этот API был только создан:

Comment: Во-первых, принцип мягкой деградации. Запросы к `Service B` могут падать, но не ломать `Service A`, обрабатывать ошибки 500 / etc. Во-вторых, обязательно настроить / иметь возможность rollback к предыдущему деплою, при желании с мониторингом и порогами (для автоотката).  В-третьих, версионирование API и планирование изменений (иногда проще делать несколько маленьких релизов), удаление старый версий спустя пару релизов.